# IntelliJ: Why when I try to mark lower level source/test folders and then change pom.xml, folder markings are reset?

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

So I am using IntelliJ and I tried to mark my folders based on the structure suggested by Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io/)

Here is what I want to achieve (two source roots, a resource and a test resource folder and a tests root folder):

[image]

When I make any change in the pom.xml it resets my marking to:

[image]

I am curious why this happens.. It doesn't happen when I have two top level folders src and test.. I am using IntelliJ 2016.3.4.

Here is my pom.xml if it makes any difference:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
        <spark.version>2.0.2</spark.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.0</hadoop.version>
        <spring.version>5.0.0.M5</spring.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.5.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <!-- Sonar -->
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-greghaskins-maven</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/greghaskins/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>cvut-snapshots</id>
            <name>Cvut</name>
            <url>https://repository.fit.cvut.cz/maven/remote-repos/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mvn-repository-com-artifacts</id>
            <name>mvnrepository.com</name>
            <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-snapshots</id>
            <name>apache snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mvn-alfresco</id>
            <name>alfresco.com</name>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.greghaskins</groupId>
            <artifactId>spectrum</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jeremyh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jBCrypt</artifactId>
            <version>jbcrypt-0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.flextrade.jfixture</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfixture-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mifmif</groupId>
            <artifactId>generex</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dse-graph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tinkergraph-gremlin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tinkergraph-groovy</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>tinkergraph-gremlin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>javax.measure</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>unit-api</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>tec.uom</groupId>
            <artifactId>uom-se</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>systems.uom</groupId>
            <artifactId>systems-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>systems.uom</groupId>
            <artifactId>systems-quantity</artifactId>
            <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>systems.uom</groupId>
            <artifactId>systems-unicode</artifactId>
            <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>systems.uom</groupId>
            <artifactId>systems-parent</artifactId>
            <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
        <!--    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>com.xxxx.SpringBootApp</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>xxxx</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please share your `pom.xml`.

Comment: ok I put it in my question!

Comment: Your `pom.xml` overrides Maven defaults via this line: `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`.

Comment: interesting those must be from the times I was using eclipse! Let me check please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pom.xml` overrides Maven defaults via this line: `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`, therefore `src` is configured as Source root when importing. Remove this line to restore the original behavior.

Comment: I also removed ```<resources><resource><directory>resources</directory</resource></resources>``` this was causing resource markings to be reset as well